# Loss not Converging for CNN Model

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, computer-vision, pytorch, conv-neural-network

Image Transformation and Batch

```
transform = transforms.Compose([

                                transforms.Resize((100,100)),

                                transforms.ToTensor(),

                                transforms.Normalize([0.485,0.456,0.406],[0.229,0.224,0.225])

                                ])

data_set = datasets.ImageFolder(root="/content/drive/My Drive/models/pokemon/dataset",transform=transform)

train_loader = DataLoader(data_set,batch_size=10,shuffle=True,num_workers=6)
```

Below is my Model

```
class pokimonClassifier(nn.Module):

  def __init__(self):

    super().__init__()

    self.conv1 = nn.Conv2d(3,6,3,1)

    self.conv2 = nn.Conv2d(6,18,3,1)

    self.fc1 = nn.Linear(23*23*18,520)

    self.fc2 = nn.Linear(520,400)

    self.fc3 = nn.Linear(400,320)

    self.fc4 = nn.Linear(320,149)

  def forward(self,x):

    x = F.relu(self.conv1(x))

    x = F.max_pool2d(x,2,2)

    x = F.relu(self.conv2(x))  

    x = F.max_pool2d(x,2,2)

    x = x.view(-1,23*23*18)

    x = F.relu(self.fc1(x))

    x = F.relu(self.fc2(x))

    x = F.relu(self.fc3(x))

    x = F.log_softmax(self.fc4(x), dim=1)

    return x
```

Creating Instance of model, Use GPU, Set Criterion and optimizer
Here is firsr set `lr = 0.001` then later changed to `0.0001`

```
model = pokimonClassifier()
model.to('cuda')
criterion = nn.CrossEntropyLoss()

optimizer = torch.optim.Adam(model.parameters(),lr = 0.0001)
```

Training Dataset

```
for e in range(epochs):

  train_crt = 0

  for b,(train_x,train_y) in enumerate(train_loader):

    b+=1

    train_x, train_y = train_x.to('cuda'), train_y.to('cuda')

    # train model

    y_preds = model(train_x)

    loss = criterion(y_preds,train_y)

    # analysis model

    predicted = torch.max(y_preds,1)[1]

    correct = (predicted == train_y).sum()

    train_crt += correct

    # print loss and accuracy

    if b%50 == 0:

        print(f'Epoch {e} batch{b} loss:{loss.item()} ')

    # updating weights and bais

    optimizer.zero_grad()

    loss.backward()

    optimizer.step()

  train_loss.append(loss)

  train_correct.append(train_crt)
```

My loss value remains between 4 - 3  and its not converging to 0.

The dataset I am using is here: https://www.kaggle.com/thedagger/pokemon-generation-one

Answer (score 1):

The problem with your network is that you are applying `softmax()` twice - once at `fc4()` layer and once more while using `nn.CrossEntropyLoss()`.

According to the [official documentation](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/nn.html#torch.nn.CrossEntropyLoss), Pytorch takes care of `softmax()` while applying `nn.CrossEntropyLoss()`.

So in your code, please change this line

```
x = F.log_softmax(self.fc4(x), dim=1)
```

to

```
x = self.fc4(x)
```

Comment: If that is the case then you have to add more layers and make network more complex. Take inspiration from state of the art architectures like Resnet,Alexnet etc and make your own custom network or you can use transfer learning as well.